# Why does Cython crash Python?

Tags: python, cython

I've just started using Cython and am trying to implement a simple Fibonacci function as described here:

http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

The problem is that when I try to run the function for a given input, within Spyder, the kernel dies and python crashes.

Specifically, if I open Spyder and run

```
%%file cython_fib.pyx
def fib(n):

    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:

        print b,
        a, b = b, a + b
```

then the file cython_fib.pyx is created. Then I can run

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import cython_fib
```

to import the Cython function cython_fib. At this stage of the process Spyder is using around 80% of the memory. When I try to call the function,

```
cython_fib.fib(2000)
```

the IPython console in Spyder throws up the error

```
It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
```

repeatedly.

What is causing this crash? Clearly using Cython is using up a lot of memory, but this shouldn't be an issue for such a simple example.

I am using Anaconda 2.0.1 with Python 3.4 on Windows 7.

Comment: It works for me. I'm not using Spyder, though. Can you try it outside of Spyder to see if it runs or you get a better error message?

Comment: @Veedrac If I try either running the script through the IPython notebook or through the command line, my python crashes and a Windows error pops up saying python.exe has stopped working. Does this mean it is my system that is the issue? I can test it out on a different computer some time next week.

Comment: It seems pretty likely that the installation is problematic, yes. Trying on another computer might help. Trying when `fib` is just `pass` might also help. Without a better error message it's hard to know what the problem is.

Comment: @Veedrac Okay. I will try another computer at the weekend and see what happens. Even a function that doesn't do anything still crashes python.